# I am trying to get Hadoop psuedo cluster detail using api in java

Tags: hadoop

I am learning hadoop
I am trying to get my pseudo hadoop cluster details like name node, data node live node, dead node etc from java code using hadoop api
i.e.
what ever we can see using http port i.e 50070.
For this i have tried using 
FSNamesystem class but not able to call its constructor as it is private for different package so i m thinking if some how i can give dependency injection for namenode and configuration class which are the argument for this constructor so that i can use as shown below :

FSNamesystem f= FSNamesystem.getFSNamesystem();
f.getLiveNode() and all remaining methods

can any one suggest how i can implement this

thanks in advance